# Read metadata in mp3 / aac using JS

Tags: javascript, mp3, aac

I was looking for a way to read metadata from `audio`, but couldn't find anything (old links).
I would like to read the content of metadata from aac or, alternatively, from mp3, which is in the `<audio>` tag.
The files are hosted on the server and I would like to read the title and author.
I have implemented using the jQuery library.

I would be grateful for help.

Comment: I've found this repository to be quite good:  https://github.com/Borewit/music-metadata-browser  Also note that there's probably no reason you need jQuery.  At least in my own web dev, I haven't needed to use it in almost a decade.

Comment: I am more interested in checking the metadata on the client side.

Comment: That's what that code does...